# How do I remove the 'category' from the URL using wordpress with my custom structure?

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress, permalinks

My current premalink settings are the 'Custom Structure': `http://example.com/mysite/%category%/%postname%/`

while having a "." (dot) in the 'Category base' line.

what makes my sites URL look like this when entering a category.

```
http://www.example.com/fruits
http://www.example.com/vegetables
http://www.example.com/nuts
ect'.
```

(sorry cant post links)

I want sub-categories work the same. ex:

```
http://www.example.com/category-name/sub-category-name
http://www.example.com/category-name/sub-category-name/post-view
http://www.example.com/fruits/bananas
http://www.example.com/fruits/apples/10facts-about-apples
http://www.example.com/vegetables/potatoes
```

While showing the posts related to the sub-categories.

The problem is that when I want to view a sub-category under a category (www.mysite.com/fruits/bananas, lets say "fruits" is my category and my sub-category under it is "bananas", I can't see posts that are under that bananas subcategory, unless I remove the "." (dot) from the "Category base" option.
but then I get:
http://www.example.com/category/fruits/bananas 
and then I do see the posts. 
so how do I remove the "category" the right way, so that I will be able to see the posts under the subcategory and have a nice URL the way I want it ?

Thank you :).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

I used: **/%category%/%postname%.html**

in 'Custom Structure'

and: **/.**

in 'Category base'